# Programming Quiz Q

Tags: python

so basically, I am relatively new to programming in general.  Recently, I had a quiz that had to do with objects and classes.  Here is the question:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 1
        self.__y = 1

    def getY(self):
        return self.__y
a = A()
a.__y = 45
print(a.getX())
```

Here are the multiple choice options:

A. The program has an error because x is private and cannot be access outside of the class.

B. The program has an error because y is private and cannot be access outside of the class.

C. The program has an error because you cannot name a variable using __y.

D. The program runs fine and prints 1.

E. The program runs fine and prints 45.

Initially, I had thought that I would get an error because of the last line of code:

```
print(a.getX())
```

because there is no method in class A called getX, but that is not an option.
After, I had selected D.

The correct answer is supposedly B, but I thought that, 'Sure, you can't change it, but it wont spit an error'.

Am I missing something or did my teacher have the wrong answer?

Comment: You need to find a different course; there's clearly a typo in the question and the *"correct"* answer is at best a simplification and at worst betrays a misunderstanding of what's actually happening (not to mention how Python approaches public/private attributes and getters/setters).

Comment: You can simply try and run this. AttributeError: A instance has no attribute 'getX'. If it's a typo and it actually is getY, then it runs fine and outputs 1.

Comment: Python has no concept of public or private access.

Comment: *F. The question has an error because there are no private members in Python, and all that’s going on here is name mangling that prevents you from accessing `__y` on the object.*

Comment: without the typo, the answer is D because of name mangling

Comment: C is partially correct; `a` now has two attributes related to `__y`: the mangled one for which `a.getY()` will return 1, and the unmangled one you set directly on `a` that has value `45`. (Compare `a.__y` with `a.getY()`.) Which means that @jonrsharpe is right and you need to find a course that proofreads and doesn't gloss over important details.